# How can I position ShareThis buttons manually when using the plug-in?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

In developing custom themes I have clients who want to use ShareThis for their social media. ShareThis offers a plug-in with a control panel that lets the client manage the buttons, style, etc. the trouble is that the ShareThis plug-in renders the buttons using a filter on `the_content`. This means that the button must always appear right after the main content block. Is there some way I can manually control placement of the ShareThis buttons in my templates when using the plug-in? I know that I could manually place the ShareThis code in my templates, but then the client wouldn't have control inside the Wordpress Control panel.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, at the moment I am able to do what I want using this methodology. I'm not sure if it's the best way and I have not tested it outside my development environment. It seems to work so far. I'm hoping this inspires some feedback and possibly other solutions.

The basic idea is this:

1) Disable the built in calls to ShareThis that insert the buttons automatically on pages and posts (they do this with a call to `add_filter('the_content', 'st_add_widget');` around line 285 in the `sharethis.php` file in the plugin).

2) create my own action that can be called to insert the ShareThis widget where I want in my template.

3) Do all this in `functions.php` so I don't have to hack the plug-in or Wordpress core. Doing it this way should allow WP and plug-in updates to run without any future issues.

**Solution**
Added this to my `functions.php`

```
//remove share this from all content
function remove_sharethis() {
  remove_filter('the_content', 'st_add_widget');
  remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'st_add_widget');
  remove_action('wp_head', 'st_widget_head');
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_sharethis' );

function print_sharethis_widget( ){
    print st_widget_head();
    print st_add_widget('');
}
add_action( 'custom_sharethis_widget','print_sharethis_widget');
```

Then in my templates I call the `custom_sharethis_widget` action where I want the ShareThis buttons to appear. like this:

```
<div id="my-sharethis"><?php do_action( 'custom_sharethis_widget' ); ?></div>
```

It took me a while to work this out, so hopefully this helps someone else out.

Comment: Appreciate your work on this but it involves modifying the plugins code.

Comment: @BradDalton Technically this changes the plug-ins behavior, but it doesn't modify their code. I'm using a call to `remove_filter()` in my theme's function.php file. I do not recommend editing a plug-ins code directly and I'm not doing that with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The [sharethis plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/share-this/) has NOT been coded correctly using filters and may display the buttons in the sidebar therefore you may consider installing the code manually.

**With the plugin installed**

You'll need to use all 3 code snippets

What you need to do firstly, is remove the buttons which you can do using this code in your child themes functions.php file.

```
function remove_share_this() {
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'st_add_link' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'st_add_widget' );
remove_filter('the_content', 'st_add_widget');
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'st_add_link' );
}
add_action( 'loop_start', 'remove_share_this' );
```

**This method enables you to display the buttons without installing the plugin.**

Only need these 2 steps

Then you need to add the script to the pages you want to display the buttons on.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "your-pub-i.d", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

I used a themes script box however you could load this conditionally and hook it in using [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)

Then you add the span tags to your page which you can do using WordPress or theme specific hooks, otherwise directly in your template like single.php

```
<span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest_large' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
```

Comment: In the **With the plugin installed** you propose would I still use the call to my custom `print_sharethis_widget()` method to handle display in my template? Also, what's the advantage of using the `loop_start` hook vs. the `template_redirect` hook for the `remove_share_this` call?

Comment: I wouldn't use the plugin because i think Addthis is better however i think adding the buttons manually in any hook location without the plugin is a better option.